# key map: combined keys to combined keys

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xkb, xdotool

In short, I want to map Ctrl+H/L to Ctrl+Left/Right without `autokey`, and `xbindkeys`+`xdotool`/`xvkbd` does not work. Details are as follows:

I am now using `autokey` to achieve the mapping, it works very good, but in some application it fails to work because `autokey` is a high-level application. So I want to achieve a low-level key map.

Application such as `xmodmap` and `xkb` cannot do this because Ctrl+Left/Right is not a keysym. I have tried `xbindkeys`+`xdotool`. The following configuration script for `xbindkeys` does not work:(to simplify the question, I map the keys to 'a' instead Ctrl+Left/Right)

```
#.xbindkeys
"xdotool key a"
Control+h
```

I think it is because the pressed keys influence the execution of `xdotool`, because the following works:

```
#.xbindkeys
"xdotool key --clearmodifier a"
Control+h+Release
```

But I just do not want to trigger the command when I release the key, I want it to take into effect immediately when I press the key, so I change the configuration to:

```
#.xbindkeys
"xdotool keyup h; xdotool key --clearmodifier a"
Control+h
```

This configuration still works, but it cannot achieve autorepeat, that is when I press the key board without release for a long time, the command only execute one time. I have also tried `xvkbd` but is does now work:

```
#.xbindkeys
"xvkbd -text 'a'"
Control+h
```

Can anyone give me some help to achieve my key map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I underestimated the power of xkb, it can do much more than I thought. It is the most basic and overall keyboard manager of X-server. I have met my requirement using xkb. A ***very*** useful tutorial can be found at [here on the Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension), if you are also interested in how to do that. It is also welcomed to post on this topic.

Here are the details for my case (though I strongly recommend reading the linked page because it is very useful and not too long):

First, get your present keyboard layout:

```
xkbcomp $DISPLAY ~/.config.xkb
```

Then open the `.config.xkb` file with some editor, say vscode. You can see the file consists of 5 blocks(keycodes, types, compatibility, symbols, geometry):

```
xkb_keymap {
xkb_keycodes "..." {...};
xkb_types "..." {...};
xkb_compatibility "..." {...};
xkb_symbols "..." {...};
xkb_geometry "..." {...};
}
```

In the `xkb_types` block, add:

```
type "newType" {
    modifiers= Shift+Control;
    map[Shift]= Level2;
    map[Control]= Level3;
    map[Shift+Control]= Level3;
    level_name[Level1]= "Base";
    level_name[Level2]= "Shift";
    level_name[Level3]= "Control";
};
```

In the `xkb_symbols` block, find the following two sub-blocks:

```
key <AC06> {
    type= "ALPHABETIC",
    symbols[Group1]= [               h,               H ]
};
key <AC09> {
    type= "ALPHABETIC",
    symbols[Group1]= [               l,               L ]
};
```

And change these two sub-blocks to:

```
key <AC06> {
    type= "newType",
    symbols[Group1]= [               h,               H,            Left ],
    actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<LEFT>) ]
};
key <AC09> {
    type= "newType",
    symbols[Group1]= [               l,               L,            Right ],
    actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<RGHT>) ]
};
```

Finally, reset the keyboard layout to the modified one:

```
xkbcomp ~/.config.xkb $DISPLAY
```

***Appendix***

In case that one will want to know how to map to Left/Right instead of Control+Left/Right, I add the appendix.

The only change is to replace the sub-blocks in `xkb_symbols` block with

```
key <AC06> {
    type= "newType",
    symbols[Group1]= [               h,               H,            Left ],
    actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<LEFT>, clearmods=Control) ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great!