# Puzzling phenomena in keymap with xkbcomp

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

To achieve a low-level swap of left `ctrl` key and `capsLock` key, I used `xkbcomp` as follows:

First get the present keyboard layout:

```
 xkbcomp $DISPLAY output.xkb
```

Then I change the 2 lines in `output.xkb` from

```
<LCTL> = 62;
...
<CAPS> = 66;
```

to

```
<CAPS> = 62;
...
<LCTL> = 66;
```

Then run

```
xkbcomp output.xkb $DISPLAY
```

to take it into effect. It works perfectly in most desktop applications. But the problem is with `vscode`. Actually it also works well in the normal mode of `vscode`, but when I try to change a shortcut in `vscode` and it prompt me to press new keys to change the shortcut, I pressed the `capsLock` key on my keyboard and `vscode` thinks that I pressed `ctrl`+`capsLock` simultaneously. This is not what I expected, `vscode` should not know my `capsLock` key, it should only know I pressed `ctrl` key because `XServer` should only tell `vscode` that I pressed `ctrl` key. I think it is because my configuration is not complete so that `vscode` could still detect my `capsLock` key. Can anyone tell me how to do a complete swap of `ctrl` and `capsLock`? `xmodmap` should not be the solution because it is based on `xkbcomp` and with limited function.

Comment: Did you know there is already an option to swap Ctrl and Caps in `man xkeyboard-config`? Try `setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have the same behavior as you in VSCode, but I am using the following workaround until further notice:

```
xkbcomp $DISPLAY output_orig.xkb
xkbcomp $DISPLAY output_mod.xkb
```

Edit the file *output_mod.xkb* according to my ideas.

If I work in vscode normaly, I use

```
xkbcomp output_mod.xkb $DISPLAY
```

If I edit keyboard shortcuts, I use before:

```
xkbcomp output_orig.xkb $DISPLAY
```

Make my changes with original-keys and then set the layout back to key swap:

```
xkbcomp output_mod.xkb $DISPLAY
```

Ok, that's not very clever but effective for this particular problem.

/// EDIT ///

After some research, it seems like there is a better solution especially for the *vscode behavior*:

In Terminal:

```
nano ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json
```

Insert code:

```
{
    "keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"
}
```

If code already exists in this file:

```
{
    "bla": "blub",
    "keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"
}
```

Restart vscode.

Comment: Actually I have no problem in configuring the shortcut in `vscode`, because I have two `ctrl` key on my keyboard and I can use the other to configure in `vscode`. What I am interested is how `xkb` works. Because in my mind every GUI application is based on `xserver` so `vscode` cannot detect `capsLock`. Anyway, thanks to your reply, I know it is a problem of myself.

Comment: Actually, the above problem with `xkbcomp` does not bother me. What does is another problem, I am mapping  `ctrl+j/k` to `left/right` at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289458/key-map-combined-keys-to-combined-keys/1289571#1289571 and it works finely in normal application. But in `vnc` it be recognized as `ctrl+left/right` instead of `left/right` alone.

Comment: It looks like this issue existed in *vscode* three years ago: [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32037), so especially for *vscode* this litte workarround: `"keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"` in file `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json` works for me too.